# Corefinement of two meshes with CGAL, obtaining the intersection polylines

Tags: cgal

How could I identify the polylines of intersection, from the own meshes resulting from the corefinement using CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::corefine()?, but without having to use additionally CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::surface_intersection(), for example, what repeats the intersection calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would having the edges in both meshes sufficient?
If so, you can use the named parameter [edge_is_constrained_map](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/group__PMP__corefinement__grp.html#ga6447dee822aaf92016f34512ce0b3456) to mark the edges that are at the intersection. If you don't want to iterate over the edges of the mesh to collect them, you can write a property map that will collect them (IIRC, `put` is only called once per halfedge).
If not, it should be possible to get it but not with the public API.

Comment: Thanks sloriot. In my algorithm I need to be able to traverse the intersecting edges in both meshes to simultaneously access the incident triangles of both meshes at each intersection edge. With the named parameters, as you indicate, I could do it, but with some extra preprocessing.

I want to perform this process as efficiently as possible, because I must apply my algorithm on massive amounts of meshes. I do not have experience with Property Maps, I will have to investigate these to apply your recommendation…

Comment: …Alternatively, to reduce the overhead of linking the edges at the intersection of the two meshes after calling to corefine(), I had thought of implementing my own corefinement of meshes. I thought to use CGAL::intersection() to obtain segments of intersection between triangles, together with “Intersecting Sequences of dD Iso-oriented Boxes”, and use Euler operations to corefine the triangles in both meshes with the obtained segments. Do you think that this approach, or another one that you can recommend me, could end up running faster than what you recommended to me before?

Comment: I would not recommend to re-implement it, handling all the border cases is complicated. What you need already exists it is just not publicly available. I would definitely recommend to use the property map and if this is the limit factor of your code, then contact me in private and we'll see how we can add an entry point to the function.